# How to compute the inverse of a unitary B when it's defined only by B|0⟩=XXXX?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

I got confused when reading an article about linear combination of unitary method. It shows its process as the following:

[image]

I can't figure out how the effect of $B^{\dagger}$ is calculated with the limited information of $B$.

[Here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/95812/PhysRevLett.114.090502.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)
is the article mentioned.

Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that you don't need to calculate the inverse of $B$. What you really want to evaluate is
$$
(\langle 0|\otimes I)(B^\dagger \otimes I)(\text{select}(V))(B\otimes I).
$$
So, the point is that you only need $\langle 0|B^\dagger$ which is the Hermitian conjugate of $B|0\rangle$, which you know.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer!

I am getting it like this: since directly deducing the actual form of  $W|0\rangle|\psi\rangle$ is hard, we split it into two parts: the part whose first register is $|0\rangle$ and the remaining part.

For the part whose first register is $|0\rangle$, we reduce $|0\rangle$ to 1 by multiplying $\langle 0|\otimes I$ in the left, and can see that it can be deduced to $\frac 1s|0\rangle U|\psi\rangle$ in the end. Therefore the remaining part would be some $\sqrt {1-\frac 1{s^2}}|\Phi\rangle$ with $|\Phi\rangle$ orthogonal to $|0\rangle$. 

Am I right?

Comment: Exactly!   ________

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out!